# Javascript HTML5 play() not working in ios9 Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, ios9

I have a basic HTML5 video player without controls like so...

```
<video id="videoPlayer" preload="auto" webkit-playsinline>
<source id="videoSourceMP4" src="" type="video/mp4" />
<source id="videoSourceOGG" src="" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

A button is laid over top that when pressed loads the desired video:

```
document.getElementById("videoSourceMP4").src = "videos/video.mp4";
document.getElementById("videoSourceOGG").src = "videos/video.ogg";
document.getElementById("videoPlayer").load();
```

I also now begin checking if the video canplaythrough and should begin playing using:

```
document.getElementById("videoPlayer").oncanplaythrough = function(){
document.getElementById("videoPlayer").play();
}
```

This worked in ios8, however ever since ios9 nothing happens. The video is stuck on the first frame and doesn't play. Even if I add another button on top with play() assigned nothing happens.  I have to enable the controls and play it using the play button provided. If I pause the video and then press my own play button it will work. I want to be able to use my own designed controls.

Does anyone know why this is doing this now?

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Oddly, if you use Safari and add the same page to the Home Screen, the video will play.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works as follows;

- iOS 9.2.1 - video plays full screen when the button is pressed

  - From home screen the video plays inline
- iOS 9.3 beta 1 - video plays inline when the button is pressed

  - From home screen the video plays inline

The video files are from http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <style>
    video{
        width:400px;
        border: 2px dashed black;
    }
    button{
        font-size:2em;
        padding:1em;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
    <video id="videoPlayer" preload="auto" webkit-playsinline>
        <source id="videoSourceMP4" src="" type="video/mp4" />
        <source id="videoSourceOGG" src="" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
    <br/>
    <button type='button' onclick='go()'>Play</button>
    <script>
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("videoPlayer").oncanplaythrough = function(){
            document.getElementById("videoPlayer").play();
        }
    }
    function go(){
        document.getElementById("videoSourceMP4").src = "small.mp4";
        document.getElementById("videoSourceOGG").src = "small.ogg";
        document.getElementById("videoPlayer").load();
    }
    </script>
</body>
```